# google maps custom control showing behind map on mobile devices

Tags: google-maps

My custom map control is showing up behind the map on mobile devices.

When you move the map around with you finger you can see the control behind the map, when you stop moving the map it disappears behind the map.  Everything works fine on desktop browsers.

Does anyone know if there is a setting or css that I can add to force it to be in view on mobile devices?

```
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.964885,-104.613528),
            zoom: 5,
            maxZoom: 24,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            mapTypeId: opts.mapType,
            streetViewControl: false,
            panControl: false
        };

        // Initialize map, infowindow and create default marker icon 
        map = new google.maps.Map( elem, mapOptions );

        var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');

        var controls = $("<div></div>")
            .attr("id","mbb-map-control-wrapper")
            .css({
                "margin-top": 5
            })
            .appendTo(controlDiv);

        var showMore = $("<span>Show More</span>")
            .attr("id","mbb-showmore-btn")
            .appendTo(controls);

        $(showMore).click(function(){
            $(elem).trigger("map_show_more");
        });

        var searchHere = $("<span>Search Here</span>")
            .attr("id","mbb-searchhere-btn")
            .css({
                "margin-left": 10
            })
            .appendTo(controls);

        $(searchHere).click(function(){
            $(elem).trigger("map_search_here");
        });

        $("<div></div>").addClass("mbb-clear").appendTo(controls);

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(controlDiv);
```